# In FlashPoints, how is each conversation decided?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

While in a Flashpoint, all group members make decisions in a conversation, then the game chooses one of the responses.

However, in my experience, this is not a random choice (or I have tremendously bad luck).  How does the game decide which response is chosen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you've just been unlucky.

> There is a group roll and the player who wins the roll says the dialogue option they chose. Everyone hears that player’s choice and the deal with the consequences of that choice.

This can lead to some interesting conversation dynamics if the leader is in the minority.

One important detail to note is that Light side and Dark side points are not awarded to the group for the choice depicted, but for each player individually according to the choice they made individually.

Source: [Interview with developers](http://tor-talk.com/swtor-innovations/flashpoints/)

This matches what the Developers said when they walked through one of the first flashpoints - The Esseles.

Finally, the 1.1 patch notes allude that the game tries to "normalize" conversation rolls to make sure who "wins" each roll is approximately equal.

> Players who spectated conversations no longer unleash an initial massive critical social roll in their next multiplayer conversation.

The above quote would seem to indicate that not getting to speak in one social roll gives a boost in your *next* social roll, resetting when you finally get a chance to speak.

Comment: Would also like to point out that Light or Dark Side points are awarded on your intentions... not on the choice of the one who speaks on behalf of the group.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point.

Comment: I asked this question, because the only Flashpoint I was in had upwards of 40 conversation choices in it, and the only one where my response was selected was the destination at the end (which, being after the last boss is defeated, has no bearing on the story).

Comment: @Powerlord Random is random, I guess. Got another source that says the same thing. Editing it in now.

Comment: @Fredy31 I was about to post a question about that! I picked a random answer of yours and upvoted in thanks :P

Comment: Not only is it random, you can see everyones roll (including your own) in the bottom-left of any conversation, the roll seems to go from 0-255. The same thing holds true for skill rolls (like "flirt", "lie", etc.)

Comment: Supposedly every time you *don't* get a say adds a bonus to the next roll. It's still entirely possible to get through a very long conversation without getting a single word in edgewise, but they've done their best to make it unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Numerically, each person rolls a d100 (random number between 1 and 100), with a bonus of 20 for each time you lose. The highest wins.

E.g., d100 the first time you get asked, d100+20 if you failed that, then d100+40 the next ... reseting back to d100 after you win one. (Logically, this makes it impossible to lose six times in a row when traveling with a single person).

You get twice as many social points when you win, as well as the opportunity to decide what actually happens in a quest if hitting an actual decision point.

I haven't worked out what happens with a tie; I've seen them happen and one person wins, but I can't judge why. I'll assume a hidden internal coin-flip, or possibly it picks whoever has lost more at that point.

Comment: From what I have seen ties are settled by who ever picked their option first.