# What do the numbers next to your portrait in group conversations mean?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When in a group and after / during the choices section of a conversation a number appears in the bottom-right of each members portrait.

[image: Group portrait]

I'm guessing that it is the roll result for what choice is used as the answer but cannot confirm. Does anyone know?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/42210/1134 Though this one is a little more general; same Answer applies for both though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct. This is how the game decide's who's conversation choice is the one to be picked.

Comment: The numbers appear to range anywhere from 1 to 200, although it appears to favor the low end.

Comment: I don't what the limit is but it isn't 200. Once or twice I have seen numbers around 230.

Comment: Everytime you "lose" a roll (meaning you don't get the next line) a certain amount of points is added to your next roll. I think it's cumulative but I wouldn't even know how to start making scientific research on that...